# How to cause a slight delay of conditional rendering in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**I want to delay the conditional rendering of the  progreeBar Component  to 1.5 sec if  the below condition is true**

the method that I have already tried I try using setTimeOut with use effect but that didn't work also I don't know if I implemented this method  right so any help will be welcome too.

```
function UploadScreen({ onDone, progress = 0.23, visible = false }) {
  
  var progressWidth = progress;
 

  
    return (
      <Modal visible={visible}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {progress < 1 ? (
          <Progress.Bar
            color={colors.primary}
            progress={progressWidth}
            width={200}
          />
          ) : ( 
          <LottieView
            autoPlay
            loop={false}
            onAnimationFinish={onDone}
            source={require("../assets/animations/done.json")}
            style={styles.animation}
                />       
        )}
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: _"I want to delay the conditional rendering"_ - why? What's the problem you're trying to solve with this delaying solution?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is  my posting files to the server animation issues  the progress bar component doesn't complete loading then the LottieView animation just popup if I can delay on progressBar for 1.5 sec then it will complete the loading process, I tested it by changing the value in the if condition to 1.5 and my progress bar loaded full complete

Answer (score 0):

[useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/)
Maybe this can help u